# Два одинаковых тэга с разной информацией

Tags: python, html, requests, beautiful-soup

Есть контейнер, в котором хранятся нужные мне данные.
Есть два одинаковых тэга `dd`, в которых разная информация. В HTML документе встречаются контейнеры в которых только один из этих тэгов. Как сделать что-бы **BeautifulSoup4**, при отсутствии `<dd>57x57x9</dd>`, не забирал значение `<dd>классический, современный</dd>`?

```
<div class="cat-card js-catcard" data-article="1973173" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <dl class="cat-card__params" itemprop="description">
               <dt>
                  Размер
                  </dt>
               <dd>
                  57x57x9
                  </dd>
               <dt>
                  Стиль
                  </dt>
                <dd>
                   классический, современный
                  </dd>
           </dl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доступаемся к тексту первого тэга "dd", после сделаем .strip(), чтобы убрать удаляя как начальные, так и конечные символы, а далее проверяем на наличие в строке букв.

```
soup = bs(html,'lxml')
res = soup.find('dl', class_='cat-card__params').find('dd').text

if res.strip().isalpha() != True:
    print(res)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]